# MongooseJS enum with associated value

Tags: javascript, swift, mongoose, enums

Imagine I have two possible structures for a value based on another parameter:

```
const user = {
    isInternational: false,
    city: '...'
}
```

Or

```
const user = {
    isInternational: true,
    country: '...'
}
```

My question is, how do I model that in my schemas?

Based on the "isInternational" flag I have to decided which other data is also present. In Swift there are enums with associated value for this like [Swift associated value](https://medium.com/@PhiJay/why-swift-enums-with-associated-values-cannot-have-a-raw-value-21e41d5ec11). Ps.: in Swift I wouldn't even need the flag, a single enum parameter would contain all the information.

I did look into discriminators and it does solve the problem of allowing different schemas, but it also allows the base schema, which I don't want.
I also know I could just have both fields and leave one of them blank based on the flag, but that would also require extra input validation.

I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: To be honest, I don't sure that it's even possible in JS. To handle the mongoose schema based on field value. If I were you, I'll add both fields on the schema, and handle those scenarios by `if/else` code blocks.